# Object Storage Error in IBM Data Science Experience

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, data-science-experience

I created an Object Storage account in Bluemix. I am trying to link that or view that in Data Science Experience and getting an `Unexpected response code: 500` whenever I tried to load the "Object Storage" option from within Data Science Experience. But, when I go to the Bluemix account and search for the Object Storage I am able to find it. What might be going on with Data Science Experience that I am unable to link it?

Comment: Did you use the same org and space in Bluemix and DSX?

Comment: I think this must have been a temporary issue with bluemix apis which DSX uses to access object storage service information...After i reloaded the page, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing usually happens if your first and/or last name in your IBM account has numeric characters, Object Storage does not allow numeric characters in the first or last name and will fail creating the instance.

The only fix is to modify your Bluemix account name to remove any disallowed characters.

If that is your case you can fix your Bluemix account name by signing in to My IBM Profile (https://www.ibm.com/account/profile/us) and click "Edit user information".